# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' at runtime

Tags: java, android, jvm, runtime, build.gradle

I am facing this runtime error.It says :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Here is my build.gradle script :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.stratbeans.barium.mobilebarium"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
compile files('libs/listviewanimations_lib-core-slh_3.1.0.jar')
compile project(':ListViewAnimations-core')
compile project(':StickyListHeaders')
compile project(':ListViewAnimations-core-slh')
```

Please help me out.Thanks!

Comment: " finished with non-zero exit value 2" is the bottom line.
Could you add the hole compilation log?

Comment: Most common error in Android studio

Comment: use gradle assemble --info. Also check if the single modules are using different version of support libraries (jar files)

Answer (score 1):

> You should audit your project for unwanted dependencies and remove as
>   much unused code as possible using ProGuard.

1. **Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex**
2. **Modify your manifest to reference the MultiDexApplication class**

*Modify your app Gradle build file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output .*

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.stratbeans.barium.mobilebarium"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

For details you can visit my answer [DexIndexOverflowException Only When Running Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests)

Comment: Tried this too, the same error keeps coming up. It goes when I comment this line "compile project(':ListViewAnimations-core')". But without this the google cards list view that I am trying to implement in my app won't work properly.

Comment: okay .Comment out (I mean remove this line and see the result) `compile project(':ListViewAnimations-core')`

Comment: Why would that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true 
}
```

Add multiDexEnabled true inside your defaultConfig in your build.gradle. 
Hope that will work for you!

Comment: And add this line in dependencies : compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' AND You have to add this in the android-manifest : android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" in <application />

Comment: It gave me this error on adding the above lines "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatIcs$MySearchView.class"

Comment: This means one of the dependencies added is duplicate, search it ,remove it clean and rebuild project

Comment: This dependency is causing the problem "compile project(':ListViewAnimations-core')". But I need to include it in my app or I won't have the functionality that I want.

Comment: compile files('libs/listviewanimations_lib-core-slh_3.1.0.jar')
compile project(':ListViewAnimations-core')
compile project(':StickyListHeaders')
compile project(':ListViewAnimations-core-slh')

Do you require all 4 of those? It may be repeating internally..