# Android studio Failed to run command: java -Xmx1024M -cp

Tags: android

Today I meet this question, when i use android run the program. Gradle will take mistake like this:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:createAnzhiDebugMainDexClassList'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       java -Xmx1024M -cp /Users/Hades/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/lib/dx.jar com.android.multidex.ClassReferenceListBuilder /Users/Hades/Work/Code/RentAgent/RentAgent/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/anzhi/debug/componentClasses.jar /Users/Hades/Work/Code/RentAgent/RentAgent/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/anzhi/debug/allclasses.jar
>     Error Code:
>       1
>     Output:
>       Unable to locate a Java Runtime to invoke.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting up your app development project to use a multidex configuration requires that you make a few modifications to your app development project. In particular you need to perform the following steps:

1. **Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex**
2. **Modify your manifest to reference the MultiDexApplication class**

*Modify your app Gradle build file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output .*

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Read Official Document about
[MultiDex](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html)

If your Application class is extending some other class and you don’t want to or can’t change it, **`override attachBaseContext()`** as shown below:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { 
   @Override 
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) { 
      super.attachBaseContext(base); 
      MultiDex.install(this); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot, This is very useful. But my question is because my computer RAM is not enough for android Dalvik to use gradle  build!  So i restart my computer. It is resolve !  Thank you !

Comment: @GeekHades You can read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve this question:

in the android studio terminal: input this command line

if you use Mac

```
./gradlew --stop
```

if you use windows, you can try

```
 gradlew --stop
```

It works for me!