# Gradle Build failed with unexpected error when trying to build APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have written a small code, but whenever I try to build the apk, I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.multidex.ClassReferenceListBuilder with arguments {C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\yyyyy\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\yyyyy\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar}

Where xxxx is my username, and yyyyy is project name.
I have tried all possible solutions that I found on Stack Overflow, but I realized that all of them were asked about older versions.

I have the latest version of Android Studio. I am using latest version of Android SDK, the build tools, gradle, JDK 8.0 , and JRE 7. I also tried JRE 8.

```
build.gradle(module app) :
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxx.yyyyy"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "Unreleased Demo Version"
    testInstrumentationRunner                 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: please show your `build.gradle` file of app module

Comment: if you haven't found a solution yet there is also one thing you can try. go to your project folder in disk and delete the intermediate folder and then build your project again it will work fine,

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: what is inside `libs`, which jars ?

Comment: There are no jar files

Answer (score 0):

In you build.gradle/app

```
defaultConfig {
    ....
   //Add this line
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
   ....
   //Add this line
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I have tried all possible solution including this one.It doesn't helped me

Answer (score 0):

This happens as the Android platform has continued to grow, so has the size of Android apps. When your app and the libraries it references reach a certain size, you encounter build errors that indicate your app has reached a limit of the Android app build architecture

**Modify the module-level build.gradle file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown here**: [Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

```
android {
    defaultConfig {


        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried all possible solution including this one.It doesn't helped me

Comment: After adding this  go to FILE -> Invidate Cahes / restart

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. can you help me using Teamviewer

Comment: ok try removing compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'. i updated the answer

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.multidex.ClassReferenceListBuilder with arguments {C:\xxxx\yyyyy\Desktop\VoterSearch\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\yyyyy\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar} **After Your suggestion **

Comment: Then check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666261/android-studio-failed-to-run-command-java-xmx1024m-cp

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Module:App gradle folder.

```
 multiDexEnabled true

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared any of your codes and dependencies you working with ,so it is difficult to guess exact problem.

but from error you posted ,i think your program cross the limit of 64K Methods.

Apk files conatins bytecode files in the form of DEX, and  it has a limit of 65,536 methods in a single DEX file.

So if your App has more then 64k methods ,you should go for multiple Dex files.

Enabling mutiple Dex ,means app build process will generate more than one DEX file

```
defaultConfig {
....

multiDexEnabled true 
}

dependencies {
....

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found there is no need to install JDK and JRE (ref:android studio 2.3.2 latest download page under system requirements)

And there is a folder named "jre" in programfiles/android-studio.

So I thought I shall uninstall JDK and JRE (as the problem related to java)

After this I reinstalled android studio.

And now it works fine.
(I haven't done research in deep although it helped me)

Comment: Which os?  I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

This happen when your have cross 65,536 method reference limit.

### Step 1

You can add the following to your app's build.gradle file

```
    android {
      defaultConfig {
      ...
      minSdkVersion 15 
      targetSdkVersion 25
      multiDexEnabled true
     }
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

### Step 2A

After that you have to extend the Application class in the following way

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

Or you can do as below:

### Step 2B

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

### STEP 3

Finally update your manifest file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.myapp">
   <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you explain step 2

Comment: There are two option provided in supoort library:
First is that you can extend the normal Application class and on attachBaseContext method ,you can set MultiDex.install(this)

Second is you can extend your application class from  MultiDexApplication itself ,so that you dont need to setup anything  on attachBaseContext method

Comment: Not working. Now it's showing Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

Comment: Are you using 32 bit system or 64 bit?

Comment: Windows 7 32 bit

Comment: And the jvm version means 32 or 64?

Comment: jvm is also 32. What do you want to know exactly

Comment: Try setting the below code in your gradle.properties file and  invalidate the cache  by going to FILE -> Invidate Cahes / restart

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxHeapSize\=2048m -Xmx2048m`

Comment: Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap