# java.lang.noClassDefFoundError on Android 4.4.4, works on 5.0+

Tags: java, android, gradle, gson

I am getting this error:

```
12-17 03:59:18.767 7516-8610/io.ustube.ustube E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                            Process: io.ustube.ustube, PID: 7516
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Preconditions
                                                                at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(TypeToken.java:72)
                                                                at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.get(TypeToken.java:296)
                                                                at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:644)
                                                                at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:631)
                                                                at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:586)
                                                                at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:566)
                                                                at io.ustube.ustube.LoginActivity$VerifyTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:338)
                                                                at io.ustube.ustube.LoginActivity$VerifyTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:310)
                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

but I know that the mentioned class is a dependency. I've looked through the jar file myself. Also, I only get this error below 5.0.

My gradle file includes `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'`

Answer (score 1):

> NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not
>   able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during
>   compile time. For example, if we have a method call from a class or
>   accessing any static member of a Class and that class is not available
>   during run-time then JVM will throw NoClassDefFoundError.

You can try with

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
```

Then , *Modify your app Gradle build file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output .*

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21 // Set Yours
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0" // Set Yours

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21 // Set Yours
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

More details

> [DexIndexOverflowException Only When Running Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

This thing happens a lot. You should be able to fix by doing the following,

```
multiDexEnabled = false
```

in your `build.gradle` file.

If you already have `multiDexEnabled = true` then change it to `false` or add this new line.

Comment: what is the reason for this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Use compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' then extends MultiDexApplication in your application class.

Comment: Add a code example and extra reference where to find more details. It will help other users when read it.