# Didn't find class on path DexPathList

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, ioexception, runtimeexception

I was attempting to update my project to targetSdk 23, but I decided I wasn't up for it given all the deprecations. I didn't want to go through it so I reverted to an older version on mercurial, and now all I get is this error and I can't get the damn app to run again. What could possibly be going wrong?

```
12-21 02:36:00.545      437-437/com.elgami.customizer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.elgami.customizer, PID: 437
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.elgami.application.GlobalApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.elgami.application.GlobalApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.elgami.customizer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.elgami.customizer-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:578)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.elgami.application.GlobalApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.elgami.customizer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.elgami.customizer-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:573)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.elgami.customizer-1/base.apk
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:295)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:59)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:279)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makePathElements(DexPathList.java:248)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:120)
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
            at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:65)
            at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:58)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:376)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:568)
            ... 9 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.elgami.application.GlobalApplication
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 12 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

**My build file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.elgami.customizer"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //runProguard false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.5.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.antonyt:InfiniteViewPager:v1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    // recyclerview
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    // google analytics
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    // pager sliding strip
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    // http library (for using beanstream REST)
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    // amaazon S3 uploads
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.1.+'
    // paypal purchasing
    compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.7.1.jar')
    // Module dependency on ParseLoginUI library sources
    compile project(':ParseLoginUI')
    // Parse libs
    compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar')
    // android support v4
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    // facebook SDK
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    //butterknife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    // Subsampling-scale-image-view (for templating)
    //compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.1.4'
    compile files('libs/AppRater.jar')
}
```

Comment: My app doesn't even run on debug mode. Why would I have to add multi-dex support when it was working just fine a little while ago? All I did was revert to an older version after attempting to update to Sdk 23. What could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Android application (APK) files contain executable bytecode files in
>   the form of Dalvik Executable (DEX) files, which contain the compiled
>   code used to run your app. The Dalvik Executable specification limits
>   the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX
>   file to 65,536, including Android framework methods, library methods,
>   and methods in your own code. Getting past this limit requires that
>   you configure your app build process to generate more than one DEX
>   file, known as a multidex configuration.

1. **Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex**
2. **Modify your manifest to reference the MultiDexApplication class**

*Modify your app Gradle build file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output .*

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

For more details you can visit

> [DexIndexOverflowException Only When Running Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests)

Comment: I already set multidex enabled and target and compile sdk was 25. It was running in other devices except my device sony xperia xa

Comment: @Prasad Disable Instant RUN

Comment: How can i check the instant run in the latest android studio 4.0.2