# Fatal Exception in Android Studio: Error inflating class ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-constraintlayout, inflate-exception

I'm getting the same error and cant seem to understand where it comes from. tried messing with the constraints but im keep coming back to this specific problem.

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rapp, PID: 11288
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rapp/com.example.rapp.ui.CheckListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:703)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.rapp.ui.CheckListActivity.onCreate(CheckListActivity.java:62)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.rapp-re4jZb52NhxBq505zHulTA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:35)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:693)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:954)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5639)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
                ... 6 more
Application terminated.
```

The XML file activity_check_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.CheckListActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the class that showed up in the error CheckListActivity.java:

```java
package com.example.rapp.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.rapp.R;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CheckListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CheckListView {

    // states for buttons.
    public static final int ADD_NEW_ITEM = 1;
    public static final int REMOVE_LAST_ITEM = 2;
    public static final int GOT_FOCUS = 3;
    public static final int REMOVE_ITEM = 4;
    ArrayList<String> ingredientNames = new ArrayList<>(); // list of ingredients.
    private ConstraintLayout container;
    private CheckListPresenter presenter;
    private String jsonArrayStr;


    // method to read json from assets folder.
    public String loadJSONFromAsset(Context context) {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("foods.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                json = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("success!");
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            jsonArrayStr = savedInstanceState.getString("json_array", "");
        }
//**error is happening here. **
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_list);
        container = findViewById(R.id.view_container);

        presenter = new CheckListPresenterImpl(this, getApplicationContext());

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putString("json_array", presenter.getCheckListData());
    }

    @Override
    public ConstraintLayout getContainer() {
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSavedData() {
        return jsonArrayStr;
    }

}
```

I tried adding compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2' to the xml but with no success.

EDIT: here is the gradle.build file (tried constraint-layout 1.1.2):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: you have to add a dependency for the constraintlayout library, it's not part of the sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53061877/5357676
unchecked "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy" in Setting > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant run

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to Rebild Project and clean project

Comment: exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference here to import constraint layout into the project [Add ConstraintLayout to your project](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project)

Add this in you app -> build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
}
```

In the toolbar or sync notification, click Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Comment: still getting the same error after syncing (had constraint-layout:1.1.3, tried to sync with both and clean).