# Android app crashes with "No original dex files found for dex location"

Tags: android

I got this logcat error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.grayce.ttt/com.example.grayce.ttt.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.Menu
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.Menu
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.Menu
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior(CoordinatorLayout.java:622)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:2805)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:1704)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:111)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:999)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.grayce.ttt.Home.onCreate(Home.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7232)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7221)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2964)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
04-21 22:36:20.609 17465-17465/? E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.Menu" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/lib/arm, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior(CoordinatorLayout.java:615)
            ... 30 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.grayce.ttt-FUFgpDMn4tYP9oDMk4Lokg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:729)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:812)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1034)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2357)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5870)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1679)
                ... 6 more
```

Comment: Hi Grayce, pasting a random stacktrace and especially all of it will not help others in resolving or assessing you issue. Please make a repository with your app so that others can take a look at your cod in detail.

Comment: Nice. Any questions?

Comment: how can i make the repository please i'm new

Comment: @Kirguduck yes my app scratch

Comment: Please provide your activity's java code & xml layout

Comment: @GiridharKarnik: it is worth being cautious about asking question authors to make off-site repositories. In general we want the problem to be contained within the question itself. Links are fine if they are supplementary, but bear in mind they break and change often, and then the community has an extra burden of repairing or deleting the question.

Comment: @Kirguduck https://github.com/estelle97/firstrepo

Comment: @halfer https://github.com/estelle97/firstrepo

Comment: @Zain https://github.com/estelle97/firstrepo

Comment: please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897739/java-io-ioexception-no-original-dex-files-found-for-dex-location) as it could have multiple reasons of the issue

Comment: Very useful link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Graye. Please see @Zain's link - that sounds like an exact duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

From the looks of it, it looks like a the compiler is unable to find certain resource from the AndroidSupportLibrary. I would follow on @giridhar-karnik comment and upload the project on a repo for further analysis.

For now i can advice to take a look at the API number of SupportLibrary and the compile version of your app and make sure they are the same.