# Android Studio dexDebug error on debugging an app

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

Yesterday, when I've tried to debug my app and run it on my device, the Gradle Console started to show this error right after `:mobile:dexDebug`:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":{},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/ParseFacebookUtils;","position":{},"original":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/ParseFacebookUtils;"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)"}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mobile:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I've did a little research here, and it seems to be related to the dependencies in `build.gradle` file. All of my SDKs are up to date.

build.gradle (Module: mobile):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.intap.tof"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(include: 'achartengine-1.1.0.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!

I switched back to Parse SDK 1.9.3 and suddenly it works!

Anyway, thank you guys for trying to help me with the question. Very appriciating.

Answer (score 4):

> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/parse/ParseFacebookUtils;","position":{},"original":"com.android.dex.DexException:
>   Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/ParseFacebookUtils;"}

At first Add `multidex` in your `build.gradle` section .

1. Set `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'`
2. set `compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'`
3. set `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'`
4. **Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex**
5. **Clean-Rebuild-Sync**

*Modify your app Gradle build file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output .*

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

For details Please read **[DexException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top)**

> https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this exception because the application has reached a limit of **64k methods**. So, you can enable **multidex** in your application as correctly suggested in the other answers. But, enabling multidex increases your build time and in many cases it is not preferable.

So, I would suggest you to use different proguard files for debug and release versions(in debug version don't obfuscate variable and class names). **Proguard** in most cases would help to overcome this exception. If this doesn't work then you would have to use multidex.