# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

While I searched the error message, I got many smaller questions but none of them help me. So I am asking it again. For me, this error happens while I am adding a Handler to update my UI. If I remove the handler there will be no error. Why is it happen.

[image: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.]

```
    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:  
    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:                
    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 
    'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe''
    finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

check my gradle.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.medical.trofii"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
compile project(':rangeseekbar')
compile project(':library')


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'it.dex.dexmovingimageview:dexmovingimageviewlib:0.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.1.1'
```

}

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` .

Comment: Try to install jdk1.7_65, then change your java sdk in Project Settings. I should work

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : please check the updated question.

Comment: Use gradlew assemble --info to get more info.

Comment: @VV comment `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : sorry it is not working.

Comment: @VV http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya :  I add  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'. but chage the error to    finished with non-zero exit value 3.  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: set `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`  & `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'`

Comment: @VV sorry for too late . Inform please .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : ops... that worked. Thank you. can you post it as an answer

Comment: @VV Thanks :) .Move ahead

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : :). can you tell me what was the problem. what I thought is something related with heap size.

Comment: @VV Version conflict .

Comment: @VV I have a request please add `multidex ` for better approach .details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : i am having the same error while adding   compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.12.5'. how am i suppose to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update this

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1' 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```