# Android gradle app:DexDebug error Parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, build.gradle, dex

I have build an android app and i have this error when trying to compile my app

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.>com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ********
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.211"
       // multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories { mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree('src/main/libs')
    compile fileTree('src/main/libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.+'
}
```

It says on parse.com that "Add compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.+' to your Gradle dependencies. This includes the contents of the Parse-*.jar and the com.parse:parse-android:1.10.+ repository, so be sure to remove as needed to prevent duplicate dependencies, otherwise a com.android.dex.DexException will be thrown."

and in my library i have

```
bolts-android-1.2.0.jar
Parse-1.9.4.jar
picasso-2.5.2.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
```

EDIT: when i enable multiDex in gradle i get this error

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class`

when i comment this line out `compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.+'` all works well

i am not sure how to get rid of the error being thrown when i add the above line can some one please help.

Comment: Did you try to integrate support for multidex?

Comment: use `compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.5'`

Comment: // Enabling multidex support.
        `multiDexEnabled true ` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: when i enable multidex support still error

Comment: i also tried use compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.5' still no luck

Comment: @Joey121 duplicate entry...comment `compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'` or `compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.+'`

Comment: use `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya the compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.+' im not really sure and  'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0' does not work also

Comment: you need to add this dependency compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' if multiDexEnabled is true.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i think it is the twitter one because of what parse says see question

Comment: @DavidRauca still no luck

Comment: when i comment this line out `compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.+'` all works well

Comment: @Joey121 i already mentioned you .you should use `com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.3`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i have tried it and still no luck

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
```

with:

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0') {
    exclude module: 'bolts-android'
}
```

Comment: but i still can not use the `compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.+'`

Comment: use this: compile('com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.5')

Comment: i get this error `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class`

Comment: Did you try to compile the project without this jar Parse-1.9.4.jar?

Comment: Yes. I've tried your code but without those 4 jars from libs and it worked for me.

Comment: thanks i have also deleted all the parse frameworks and added again and it works for me now

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to improve a multidex in your code, just add

```
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

in your gradle file and in your application attachBaseContext just put MultiDex.install(this) like this

```
    @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

I forgot, you need to add

```
 multiDexEnabled true
```

in your gradle file too

hope it can help you!