# During Android Firebase Admob Integration i getting the error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, admob

I'm having trouble while compiling my project and getting the following Exception please help me out.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

my app.build gradle file code is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.appid"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And check my project.gradle file code is:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: call `buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"`

Comment: i'm getting this when i tried to change '24.0.0' All packages are not available for download!  The following packages are not available:
- Package id build-tools;24.0.0

Comment: call this `targetSdkVersion 23` and gradle then

Comment: still same error check this Error:Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: yes yes .`OutOfMemoryError` Reduce image size & resolution

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: thank you @IntelliJAmiya i solved my problem by adding this line in Manifest.xml         android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

Comment: Please read my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Yep you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've found a solution to your issue via multidex, but I wanted to point out something about your build settings. In your `build.gradle` you list these:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
```

You can take out `play-services-ads`, as it's included with both `firebase-ads` and `play-services`. Also, If the only part of Play services you're using is AdMob, you can actually take out `play-services`, too.

We recently put up a blog post explaining a bit about what's in each of these artifacts, as well:

- [Importing the Mobile Ads SDK with Firebase](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2016/08/importing-mobile-ads-sdk-with-firebase.html)

Hopefully that helps sort things out a little bit!