# java.lang.RuntimeException: No dex files created at ...../instant-run

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No dex files created at E:\ad\projects\NearVeg\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\instant-run_d9024a87e9e4c0d6db37a8c6ebdfd3214367595b

i have added **multiDexEnabled true** in defaultConfig and also replaced to

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

So please don't give such advices.

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bhunnu.nearveg"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
     compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
     compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
}
```

and in manifest file :

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

one question already asked related this but still no solution at. Thank in adavance

Comment: did you create `Application` class

Comment: check this section `public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests

Comment: i have created it only for see to hash code after it removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remove error temporary i just off to Instant Run functionality of android studio.

For enable Instant just followed :

> 1) File => Setting.
>
> 2) Click to Build,Execution,Deployment.
>
> 3) Click Instant Run
>
> 4) Uncheck to Enable Instant Run to hot swap code.....