# When building an apk: DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using android studio and there are no problems when running the app only when building its apk.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]:  
65536
```

Comment: post your build.gradle file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Inside the **defaultConfig of build.gradle**

```
defaultConfig
{
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Thanks,,this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

That helped me: in your `build.gradle` add the following:

```
android {
...
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also add following in android of build.gradle along with multidexEnabled

```
dexOptions {
  javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```