# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using large icon in notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

When using a large icon in a notification this error appears and the app crashes:

```
  06-06 19:53:34.688 25207-25207/com.example.hadi.music E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hadi.music, PID: 25207
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;
        at com.example.hadi.music.service.MediaPlayerService.buildNotification(MediaPlayerService.java:90)
        at com.example.hadi.music.service.MediaPlayerService.access$100(MediaPlayerService.java:25)
        at com.example.hadi.music.service.MediaPlayerService$1.onPlay(MediaPlayerService.java:126)
        at android.media.session.MediaSession$CallbackMessageHandler.handleMessage(MediaSession.java:1150)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.graphics.drawable.Icon" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hadi.music-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hadi.music-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hadi.music-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hadi.music-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hadi.music-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hadi.music-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hadi.music-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hadi.music-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hadi.music-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hadi.music-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hadi.music-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hadi.music-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.example.hadi.music.service.MediaPlayerService.buildNotification(MediaPlayerService.java:90) 
        at com.example.hadi.music.service.MediaPlayerService.access$100(MediaPlayerService.java:25) 
        at com.example.hadi.music.service.MediaPlayerService$1.onPlay(MediaPlayerService.java:126) 
        at android.media.session.MediaSession$CallbackMessageHandler.handleMessage(MediaSession.java:1150) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.graphics.drawable.Icon
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 12 more                                                                         

    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I'm using this method to load the bitmap from url :

```
.setLargeIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(utilities.getBitmapFromURL(MusicPlayActivity.base)))


public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How can fix this problem?

Comment: [`Icon`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html) wasn't introduced until API level 23. Are you running on a prior version?

Comment: in api 23 right work but in lower api have problem

Comment: @HadiKhezrpor Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198

Comment: Let me guess... A Samsung device running Android 4.4.2?

Comment: yes in this version

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya does that DexIndexOverflowException have relationship with this error?

Comment: any solutions to this?

Comment: Does anybody fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is also reported in google issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63151548). And according to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582430/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-graphics-drawable-icon), this issue can be solved by updating your libraries to API 27 and using support library v27 or above. Do reply about whether it was solved using this or not.

Comment: I was having trouble running the layout inspector on a KitKat device while pointed at sdk level 26. The move to 27 worked, thank you!