# Android app crashes with ClassNotFoundException on some devices

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-multidex

Hi I am developing andorid applicaiton.I tried to install this application on some devices. It works fine.But on some other devices it crashes with following exception:

```
07-13 12:28:17.515 17306-17306/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.simple, PID: 17306
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application 
com.example.simple.SampleApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "com.example.simple.SampleApplication" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/com.example.simple-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/ap
p/com.example.simple-1/lib/arm, 
/data/app/com.example.simple-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, 
/system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:608)
at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5013
)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5847)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.jav
a:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.example.simple.SampleApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/com.example.simple-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/a
pp/com.example.simple-1/lib/arm, 
/data/app/com.example.simple-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, 
/system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:986)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:603)
at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5013
) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5847) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.jav
a:865) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.example.simple.SampleApplication
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot 
class loader; no stack trace available
07-13 12:33:17.714 17306-17306/com.example.simple I/RuntimeInit: RuntimeInit: enable FTRACE
```

I already enabled `multiDexEnabled true`in my gradle. Need some help to resolve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198

Comment: What is your dex settings

Comment: yes, multidex could resolve your problem.  May be this is happening because of you have added some analytical library initialised in application class. Further you can comment it incase if don't have to add multidex.

Answer (score 1):

Add below link under dependencies tag :

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Sync and run...

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle file

```
    dependencies {

       ...
        //Multi Dex
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
       ....
    }
```

In sample application class

```
 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(SampleApplication.this);
    }
```

then clean & build project

Comment: clean the project and rebuild again @nilkash

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

worked for me...
am trying to run application from mac ( was build on windows ).
It crashes on app launches.

Thanks all..