# PeripheralManagerService throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android-things

I have the following code in my app to access `PeripheralManagerService`:

```
PeripheralManagerService service = new PeripheralManagerService();
Gpio ledGpio;
try {
    ledGpio = service.openGpio("BCM6");
    ledGpio.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error configuring GPIO pins", e);
}
```

After updating to the latest Android Things (Developer Preview 7), my app is now throwing
a `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/things/pio/PeripheralManagerService;
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.things.pio.PeripheralManagerService" on path: DexPathList[...]
```

This code was working before, why has this started happening after the update?

Comment: That's a funny....  Using SO for your release notes... or as supplement anyhow.  Makes sense, it's the first place people look.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting in Preview 7, Android Things API services are not constructed as new
instances. They are instead accessed as singletons via `getInstance()` to be
more in line with Android API paradigms. Some of the classes, such as
`PeripheralManagerService` were also renamed.

Be sure to update your app to use the Preview 7 SDK:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.7-devpreview'
}
```

Then modify your code to access the `PeripheralManager` instead:

```
PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
Gpio ledGpio;
try {
    ledGpio = manager.openGpio("BCM6");
    ledGpio.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error configuring GPIO pins", e);
}
```

Review the Android Things [API reference](https://developer.android.com/things/reference/index.html)
to verify if any of the other APIs you are calling have changed.

Comment: +1. This is documented in the [release notes for 0.7-devpreview](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#preview-7)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `PeripheralManagerService service = new PeripheralManagerService();` use

```
PeripheralManager peripheralManager=PeripheralManager.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue but the above solution did not work for me. I was trying to create a alphanumeric display project by choosing new->project and choosing Android Things. The generated gradle build file looked like below. Note the driver for ht16k33 has version 0.3. This caused the problem. Once I changed it to 1.0 the ClassNotFound issue went away.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.things.contrib:driver-ht16k33:0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:+'
```

}