# Android things Raspberry pi 3 Error: After updating to the latest dependencies(Developer Preview 7)-"PeripheralManagerService can not resolved"

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

After updating to the latest dependencies(Developer Preview 7)-**"PeripheralManagerService can not resolved"**
[image: Gradle]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PeripheralManagerService throws NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141634/peripheralmanagerservice-throws-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: Agreed the link above will work. A few APIs were renamed in this release to be more consistent

Comment: @NickFelker so,How can i get more details..

Comment: Read the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141634/peripheralmanagerservice-throws-noclassdeffounderror

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using

```
PeripheralManagerService service = new PeripheralManagerService();
```

use `PeripheralManager peripheralManager=PeripheralManager.getInstance();`