# Didn't find class "com.snappydb.SnappydbException" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, snappydb

Snappy Db giving error on some specific devices -

> Didn't find class "com.snappydb.SnappydbException" on path:
>   DexPathList

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198

Comment: I already tried with this... 
problem is happening on some specific devices

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: unable to paste full build gradle

Comment: edit this in your question section .