# APK not Installing in Kitkat?

Tags: java, android

When I run through **Android Studio** is App get Installing working fine above 4.0 version...when I take apk file from **app>build>output>apk**  I am trying to install I get the error below like this...

> Note:(Same apk file working 5.0 and 6.0)

I tried all google suggestions.

**Error:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>          Pocess: app.idea.com.ideadarpan, PID: 1032
>          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application app.idea.com.ideadarpan.commonclass.Idea_Urban: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "app.idea.com.ideadarpan.commonclass.Idea_Urban" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.idea.com.ideadarpan-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/app.idea.com.ideadarpan-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
>          at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
>         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "app.idea.com.ideadarpan.commonclass.Idea_Urban" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.idea.com.ideadarpan-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/app.idea.com.ideadarpan-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
>          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
>        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553) 
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139) 
>        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353) 
>        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**APP:Builde.gradle:**   I have used **Four JAR file** for pdf and also Covert Json to Excels it's in lib folder i have to use the same version only.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.idea.com.ideadarpan"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        dexOptions {
            jumboMode true
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }

    }
    dexOptions
            {
                javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
                preDexLibraries = false
                // here heap size give 4g i got this thing from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/P_TLBTyFWVY
            }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Application Class:**

```
public class Idea_Urban extends MultiDexApplication {
    private static Idea_Urban idea_urban;
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    public static Context context;

    public int recy_postion;

    public static Idea_Urban getInstance() {
        return idea_urban;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        idea_urban = this;
        initSharedPreferences();

       }
}
```

Any one help me please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198 . You should create `Application` class .Also check first answer . `Instant Run`

Comment: I have already Application class sir as well i checked `Instant Run` ..still same problem

Comment: show please  your Application class

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya Please check sir i add

Comment: `extends Application` and `@Override public void onCreate() {
    MultiDex.install(this);` and make sure you call this in manifest section .

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya Please tell me sir...how to call in manifest file

Comment: `<application
        android:name=".Idea_Urban"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156894/discussion-between-mariyappan-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score 1):

Your given information is inconsistant.
At title, you say that not working at KitKat(4.4) but in the question, you say working above **4.0**.

Android **4.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2** is API level **14**, which is lower than your minSDK level(**15**).

If you try to run this app on 4.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2 devices, it will not work. You may update the question with exact version name you have tried.

You can lower change `minSdkVersion` at gradle.

Comment: @Mariyappan Are you using Build>Build APK steps, or just running project and taking apk file from app>build>output>apk folder?

Comment: i done I just running project and taking apk file from `app>build>output>apk folder?'` y sir is there any problem instance of Build apk

Comment: @Mariyappan try using Android Studio Top Menu>Build>Build APK and then, take the apk from /app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk location. Running the project makes a specific build and may not work other versions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make build by disabling instant run? 
 Goto File -> Settings -> Build,Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Uncheck the checkbox for instant run

This may be the reason. Plase, check that also. I am not sure about this. But just give a try :)