# Unable to Merge Dex - Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

When I updated my Android Studio to 3.0 in the stable channel and ran the project, I started getting the below error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
} 
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.med.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    resConfigs "auto"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

//appcompat libraries
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'


//butterknife
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

//picasso
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

//material edittext
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

// Retrofit & OkHttp & and OkHttpInterceptor & gson
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'

// FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have tried all the answers given but I am unable to solve this error. Please help.

Comment: show `build.gradle`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I also tried the solution of the question you linked. None of them works.

Comment: you have not enabled multidex, u need to

Comment: @NirajSanghani I also tried enabling multidex. It didn't help.

Comment: can u try it with putting google() repository with in buildscript repository

Comment: @NirajSanghani Tried. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @MehulKanzariya Did you create Application class?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Nope, I didn't create Application class.

Comment: @MehulKanzariya https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198

Comment: Try to build gradle with verbose options. In my case, I detected the problem is a library in /libs. I delete it and the problem solved.

Comment: Can you please paste your the full build.gradle file here.

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya I have added the full build.gradle file.

Comment: Did u find a solution ? I still have the same problem

Comment: @ImenNmn Nope :(

Comment: @MehulKanzariya I assume that you are not using any jars in your lib folder?

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya Yes, I am not using any jars.

Comment: @MehulKanzariya Please check my improved answer. Hope that it resolve your issue.

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya Thanks a lot, it worked.

Comment: @MehulKanzariya Welcome.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add an explicit dependency to `play-services-auth` along with your `firebase-ui-auth` dependency:

```
// FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
```

This is because `firebase-ui-auth` has a transitive dependency to `play-services-auth` and must be used with the corresponding version of `play-services-auth`. Please see [this explanation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies).

```
firebase-ui-auth
|--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth
|--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth
```

Earlier versions of the Gradle build tool did not include transitive dependencies so now versions can conflict with other `play-services` versions.

**My Issue Explained and Answered (In case anyone wants to know)**

When you upgrade to Android Studio 3.0 and update the gradle build tool version to 3.0.0, compiling of dependencies is now done differently than in earlier versions.

I recently encountered the same issue. I was using these dependencies which worked fine through Gradle version 2.3.3:

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
```

After the upgrade to gradle-build-version 3.0.0, I got the same error. Digint into it, I found that the transitive dependency of `httpmime` conflicted with the file `httpclient-android` was including.

**Description**

Let me explain this in detail. Earlier, while using gradle-tool-version 2.3.3, I was using `httpclient-android` to fetch and use the class named `org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.java` 
Expanding the transitive dependencies of `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6` showed that it has `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.6` which is the same package I wanted to use. But while compiling or syncing the build, it was excluding `org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.java` so I needed to add this dependency which includes `ContentType.java`:

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
```

Everything worked fine after that.

Once I upgraded the gradle-build-version to 3.0.0, things changed. It now included all transitive dependencies. So while compiling with the latest Android Studio with gradle-build-tool version 3.0.0, my `ContentType.java` was being compiled twice. Once from `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.6` (which is an implicit transitive dependency of `httpmime`) and again from `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1` which I was using earlier.

To resolve this issue I had to remove the existing `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1` dependency as `httpmime` would itself fetch the relevant class required for my application.

The solution for my situation: only use required dependencies and remove the `httpclient-android`

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
```

Note that this is just the case for me. You'll need to dig into your own dependencies and apply the solution accordingly.

Comment: Exactly, I was also stuck with similar issue. One of my project dependency and its transitive dependent library had a dependency  on 'com.android.volley'. So this new gradle was having having issues while merging dex files. I fixed it by adding   "exclude group: 'com.android.volley' in my gradle file.

Comment: @Bhavesh Patadiya, Please help me here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976279/dexarchivemergerexception-unable-to-merge-dex). I just got stuck and unable to resolve it.

Comment: Lucky me that your explanation happen to be related with org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android and org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime . I was getting crazy to find out about it. Thanks!

Comment: `you need to dig into the classes your are having an issue with` But how did you find out which classes you've been having an issue with? Did you run `./gradlew dependencies` and go through all transitive dependencies (marked as `xxx -> yyy` in the output)?

Answer (score 14):

First of all I enabled multidex as suggested in previous comments.

Then, if the error continues, open the Gradle Console (click on "Show Console Output" icon at left of "Messages" section) and click on the link to recompile with Debug/Info/Stack options. 
This will show further details about the error.

In my case, the error "Unable to merge dex" was caused by duplicate entries 
in "com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0".

I manually removed the conflicting library from my project and executed the "Rebuild Project" (forcing to reload the library). This solved the issue.

Comment: Where exactly did you see duplicate entries? In a build.gradle file? The actual jar in a folder? Thanks

Comment: I'm getting `com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException`, despite the fact I have multidex enabled and my project built fine before updating to Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.

Comment: I did as mentioned and got the following: Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzd;
 I tried removing FirebaseUI library, rebuilding the project and then again copying the dependency. But it's not working.

Comment: Eres una pistola

Comment: It took a long time to pinpoint and eliminate the duplicate dependencies (which I feel gradle ought to do automatically), but recompiling with stack info (showing me which class was duplicated) was the tool I needed to be able to fix it at all.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error:

com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

and ended up changing back my gradle in order to fix this issue.

app\build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
//buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'//<< Changed back to old version before my studio 3.0 update
defaultConfig { ....
```

.\build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' //<< Changed back to old version before my studio 3.0 update
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

It's not ideal as it's back dating, but it's something which worked for me and should get me there until a possible patch is released.

Answer (score 3):

Check out dependencies in your **build.gradle** (app)
if you're using 2 (or more) libraries with the same name and different version.
For example (in my case):

```
implementation files('src/main/libs/support-v4-24.1.1.jar')
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
```

Remove one, then clean and rebuild. Also note that **dependencies** is outside  **buildscript**.

Answer (score 2):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

add this line to the `:gradle` file

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this error happens, when same .jar library file is present in "libs" folder and at the same time we are trying to get the source code by adding line "compile " in app gradle file.

Any one of this, if we remove then we can overcome this error.

Hope this may helpful.

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem
i resolved it put:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

in buildscript->dependencies

build.gradle

in my file i have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Change your classpath to :

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

and sycn your Gradle.

Hope this will help.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.

Answer (score 1):

"all gsm libraries"
Thanks, it helped to solve my problem, but not only the gsm libraries, but all google libraries must have the same version.
I had this dexing error, because the com.android.support:recyclerview-v7 had a different version than the com.android.support:appcompat-v7

Android studio shows these lines with red underline in the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I did exact as the hint in below screenshot, changed 11.0.4 to 11.8.0

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

it works fine

[image: Unable to merge dex]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this error have many scenarios. In my case was a 1.8 java compile in `build.gradle` (app):

```
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
```

I removed and error was gone

Answer (score 0):

I changed the below from 11.6.0 to 11.8.0 and it worked.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error with Firebase UI Database instead. Even after enabling multiDex as suggested in the other answers I was still getting the error. Then I came to know that there is a need for the Firebase UI and the Firebase Database to be of same corresponding versions as given on the Firebase UI GitHub repository.

[Firebase UI GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

Answer (score 0):

Add this your gradle: implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

Clean project and then rebuild.this works

Answer (score 0):

This might also be too late, But I think I have an answer too. Based on my recent trials, when compiling the application, ensure that you don't have a jar file and an`'implementation'('compile' for 3.0.1 > gradle)` of the same package in the same project. In my case, I had `implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'` and `Jsoup` jar in the same project. Rookie mistake but, I learnt.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling with this more recently and have added components.  What caused it for me was adding:

compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0'

What fixed it was updating it to

compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

By add this following code in build.gradle(app module) work for me

```
android {
      defaultConfig {
          multiDexEnabled true
      }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because differ library depend same child library but the version is different so exclude one library's dependency like:

```
api (rootProject.ext.dependencies["bindingRecyclerView"]) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to do three things:

1. As i was using firebase, make sure firebase and google play services had the same version.Initially play services had a lower version.
   Mainly 12.0.1 version helped
2. Set this in app's level build.gradle

   ```
   android {  
       multiDexEnabled true   
   }
   ```
3. Again in app's level build.gradle, add

   ```
   compileOptions{
       sourceCompatibility 1.8
       targetCompatibility 1.8
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0) solved the issue for me.

First I set dependencies in my pubspec.yaml to

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2
```

and ran `flutter packages get` in my IDE's terminal.

Also I had to change the minimum target SDK version:

1. Open android/app/build.gradle, then find the line that says
   minSdkVersion 16.
2. Change that line to minSdkVersion 21.
3. Save the file.

Also, I had to open `android/app/build.gradle`, then add the following line as the last line in the file:
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Next, I had to open `android/build.gradle`, then inside the buildscript tag, add a new dependency:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       // ...
   }

   dependencies {
       // ...
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'   // new
   }
}
```

After this my app finally ran on the android emulator.

The [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#6) has a more complete walkthrough if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Strange situation, but the `multiDexEnabled` didn't help me, but the problem solved after removing the Gradle directory and rebuild the application.

Answer (score -1):

this is my gradle project

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.mobilegts.candyjump"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23

    ndk {
        moduleName "player_shared"
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this is dependencies

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.0'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
}

Comment: I think you'd better edit your answer again for others understand your idea clearly