# DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex - Android Studio 3.0 Stable

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I made:

- In "Settings"->"Android SDK"->"SDK Tools" `Google Play services` is checked and installed v.46
- Removed folder `/.gradle`
- "Clean Project"
- "Rebuild Project"

Error is:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Here is output of command `gradlew -q app:dependencies>>app_dependencies.txt`

After run of the command
`gradle :app:assembleDebug --stacktrace`
I get this:

```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

 After run of the command
`gradle :app:assembleDebug --stacktrace` 
Error is:

:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavacAn exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_152-release). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: endPosTable already set
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.DiagnosticSource.setEndPosTable(DiagnosticSource.java:136)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Log.setEndPosTable(Log.java:350)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:667)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:950)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:892)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:921)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1187)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:198)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:129)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:198)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:129)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
259 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 253 up-to-date
10:58:01: External task execution finished 'assembleDebug --stacktrace'.
```

My project gradle file:

```
apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }

    ext {
        androidApplicationId = 'com.example'
        androidVersionCode = 1
        androidVersionName = "1.1.0"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

File `:app/ build.gradle`:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            multiDexEnabled true
            applicationId "com.example"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            renderscriptTargetApi 23
            renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        }
        compileOptions {
            targetCompatibility 1.8
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
        }
        lintOptions {
            quiet true
            abortOnError false
            ignoreWarnings true
            disable 'InvalidPackage'           //Some libraries have issues with this.
            disable 'OldTargetApi'
            //Lint gives this warning but SDK 20 would be Android L Beta.
            disable 'IconDensities'            //For testing purpose. This is safe to remove.
            disable 'IconMissingDensityFolder' //For testing purpose. This is safe to remove.
        }


        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "8G"
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        }

        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/apt'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }



    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation project(':library_api')
    implementation project(':library_base')
    implementation project(':library_blur_dialog')
    implementation project(':library_countrycodepicker_dialog')
    implementation project(':library_glow_decorator')
    implementation project(':library_icons')
    implementation project(':library_loopvideo')
    implementation project(':library_section_adaper')
    implementation project(':library_taptargetview')
    implementation project(':library_ucrop')
    implementation project(':library_utils')
    implementation project(':library_utils_picasso')
    implementation project(':library_vector_compat')
    implementation project(':library_view_clock')
    implementation project(':library_view_shimmer_recycler')

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.4.2"
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.1'

    implementation "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.4.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:leanback-v17:25.4.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:25.4.0"

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.4.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v14:25.4.0"

    // rxjava
    implementation  'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.9'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.davidmoten:rxjava-extras:0.8.0.6'

    // square
     "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0",
    implementation  "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0"

    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.6.0"

    // picasso
    implementation  "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'

    // dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10"
    annotationProcessor  "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10"
    implementation "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0"
    implementation  "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"


    // jake ftw
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16'

    // FragmentWithArgs
    implementation   "com.hannesdorfmann.fragmentargs:annotation:3.0.2",
    annotationProcessor "com.hannesdorfmann.fragmentargs:processor:3.0.2",

    implementation "org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9",
    annotationProcessor "org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9",
    implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.fragmentargs:bundler-parceler:3.0.2'

    implementation "com.github.codekidX:storage-chooser:1.0.34"

    implementation 'io.github.yavski:fab-speed-dial:1.0.6'

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    // intent builder
    implementation         "com.github.marcinmoskala.activitystarter:activitystarter:1.00"
annotationProcessor  "com.github.marcinmoskala.activitystarter:activitystarter-compiler:1.00"

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'//constraint-layout
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    //font
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:expectanim:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:0.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.2'
    implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:arclayout:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.flyco.tablayout:FlycoTabLayout_Lib:2.1.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker:library:1.9'
    implementation 'com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.8'
    //Location
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2"
    implementation 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.10@aar'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2"
    //you can use newer GMS version if you need
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2"
    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.9.4@aar'
    implementation 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.5.2'
    implementation 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.futuremind.recyclerfastscroll:fastscroll:0.2.5'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2"


    implementation 'com.labo.kaji:swipeawaydialog:0.1.1'
    implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:1.0.1'
    implementation 'hanks.xyz:htextview-library:0.1.5'
    implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'//progressbar for action bar
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava-math:1.0.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.1.0'
    implementation('com.github.ihsanbal:LoggingInterceptor:2.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Application class:

```
public class TheApplication  extends Application {
...
}
```

Comment: remove `build` folder and try again - it worked for me in some cases

Comment: @pskink from all modules ? or only from :app module?

Comment: start from :app

Comment: *The third party android-apt plugin is no longer supported. You should switch to the built-in annotation processor support, which has been improved to handle resolving dependencies lazily.* from About Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0

Comment: @Selvin I dont have `apt` in dependencies, I have `annotationProcessor`

Comment: Well I don't have magic orb and you didn't provide dependencies so it was blind guess

Comment: If you can provide your list of dependencies would be great.

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya , @Selvin updated `dependencies`... maybe some libs has duplicates ?

Comment: Yes, See my answer I'm not sure about the exact issue you are facing but if you could provide your list of dependencies one of us can help you out with.

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya, @Selvin here is output of command `gradlew -q app:dependencies  >>app_dependencies.txt`
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ll5g8i5n35rha7y/app_dependencies.txt?dl=1

Comment: add:--> defaultConfig {
    ....
    multiDexEnabled true
} to your app level gradle

Comment: @SnehalGongle already added

Comment: @NickUnuchek ok, please check the google play service is set to the latest version 46

Comment: @SnehalGongle where can I check it? In "Settings"->"Android SDK"->"SDK Tools" `Google Play services` is checked and installed v.46

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
implementation('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
    }
```

instead of

```
implementation'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1'
```

The reason I've tried to explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46971548/1297214) if you want to understand the issue and solution.

Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you, a lot of thanks!!! How did you find it ...I don't know, but you're greatest developer!!!

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation!! I actually tried with all your dependencies and based on the dependencies trees(./gradlew :app:dependencies) find out that the package which was conflicting. Once thats done, you just need to make sure that library doesn't include this as some other library is implicitly adding the same "commons-validator" dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the very same issue as there was a local jar for gson in the lib module of my project. As per this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#local_jars), Library modules no longer process local JARs.

I removed the gson-*.jar and added `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'` to build.gradle instead to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add android.support.design dependency 
It worked for me

Comment: Please elaborate why you think that works and how exactly does one do this? You could add a detailed explanation that helps people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to understand the stuff of MultiDex here>https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

I used the above instructions and made my app working again :)

Answer (score -2):

My problem is not the same as yours,but I think it maybe work for you too.
You should change the value of compileSdkVersion from 25 to 26,then sync.See if it works.

Comment: @NickUnuchek so after removing `build` folder the problem persists? did you try that?