# Android build gradle failing, Error app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-multidex

Error Log

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\Android\testapp\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Code Nemesis.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.0.aar\5ded4fc43c89c2e4a62253c7f0400fc3\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))

**Gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codenemesis.testapp"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'

    // Photo dependencies
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Already tried: cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906750/getting-error-execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithmultidexlistfor

Comment: Add this to your gradle file, inside dependencies:

  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986787/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithmultidexlistfordebug)

Comment: @MohammadAli i got the same error back once i rebuild my project again

Comment: @CaoMinhVu tried but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have found out is `gms:play-services:11.8.0` has conflicts with `support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0`

disabling any one will work.

I suggest using a specific module of play services. You can check the list here
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Also use `com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.1` as the 2.6.0 uses sdk v27

Comment: Changed to implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1' , everything works fine now . Thanks