# Gradle build error Error converting bytecode to dex:Cause: com.android.dex.DexException:Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/liveData$1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

From last 3 days I'm getting this error and have tried all i could. Can anyone help me correct it. I'm using Android 3.0 and my sdk and Google play services are updated as well as i have added`multiDexEnabled true` to my code...and also tried deleting the .gradle and .idea folders and again rebuilding the....but the error is still there any help would be appreciated

> Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException:Multiple dex files define
>   Landroid/arch/lifecycle/liveData$1;

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352591/android-error-converting-byte-to-dex/34353086

Comment: also refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103576/android-build-gradle-failing-error-apptransformclasseswithmultidexlistfordebug/49103997#49103997

Comment: Tried everything in there....still the same

Answer (score 6):

I've just met the same issue and fixed it by updating the version of lifecycle library:

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0'
```

It seems that another library using in my project declare the version 1.1.0, but i was using 1.0.0.

Comment: Actually the issue is not of which lifecycle library. Instead when you open packages/libraries/android/arch/lifecycle there will be many files and in my case those files have multiplied themselves. In other words same files with same names in the same place.....and this is casthe issue....i have tried this way as well but no results...thanks for the help...i really appreciate it....but i think i have to know again start from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the latest multidex in your gradle dependencies ?

```
'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and add this

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i have the latest multiDex library `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0`
 And also have tried the options you gave...but still the same error

Comment: can we see your gradle build file what dependencies do you have ?

Answer (score 1):

This should be related to incompatible versions in your gradle library. can you past your gradle libraries here

Comment: Yes, i have found that in packages under libraries/android/arch/lifecycle there are some files which have been created twice. However I'm not able to delete then...these are read only. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the menu "Invalidate Caches / Restart...", under the File menu.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, all I had to do was to update all the libraries I was using to their respective new updates and **sync the gradle**  and **rebuild** and **run** again This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I updated libraries with new version. Need to declare all the android base libraries in the same version(If you update some libraries with new version and using some in older one will cause this kind of exception).

```
    ext { archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.0'}

dependencies {
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you add the dependence in your build.gradle?

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Yes i have the latest multiDex library `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0`

Comment: I think the package 'android.arch.lifecycle' may be import twice,maybe your library modules import it , and you import it in your main application too.
You can try to remove this package's comile in your application level build.gradle.