# ClassNotFoundException Didn't find class on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having what I believe to be dex issues, which is something pretty foreign to me. My app crashes when it tries to instantiate an OkHttpClient. I see that a lot of people have this issue, but all the common solutions (which I mention below) haven't helped. Here's my error log:

```
05-06 22:43:27.912 8714-8714/com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise, PID: 8714
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient;
at com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise.ApplicationLoader.getLatestRelease(ApplicationLoader.java:123)
at com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise.ApplicationLoader.init(ApplicationLoader.java:94)
at com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise.ApplicationLoader.onCreate(ApplicationLoader.java:250)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5740)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.OkHttpClient
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise.ApplicationLoader.getLatestRelease(ApplicationLoader.java:123) 
at com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise.ApplicationLoader.init(ApplicationLoader.java:94) 
at com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise.ApplicationLoader.onCreate(ApplicationLoader.java:250) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5740) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/Call$Factory;
at com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise.ApplicationLoader.getLatestRelease(ApplicationLoader.java:123) 
at com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise.ApplicationLoader.init(ApplicationLoader.java:94) 
at com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise.ApplicationLoader.onCreate(ApplicationLoader.java:250) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5740) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.Call$Factory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise-e7jhExlmJXSclbvr60izkA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise-e7jhExlmJXSclbvr60izkA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise-e7jhExlmJXSclbvr60izkA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise.ApplicationLoader.getLatestRelease(ApplicationLoader.java:123) 
at com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise.ApplicationLoader.init(ApplicationLoader.java:94) 
at com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise.ApplicationLoader.onCreate(ApplicationLoader.java:250) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5740) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I see multiple solutions about enabling multidexing, but my app already has multidexing enabled and my manifest also has largeHeap set to true. I've also tried this gradle solution, but it hasn't helped:

```
dexOptions{
    preDexLibraries false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Other solutions say to disable instant run, but it's already disabled. Anyone have any suggestions? Please let me know if I need to add anything else to this post.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198

Comment: My app already implements that entire solution :(