# Dex file exceeded 64k after adding appbrain-sdk:14.30

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I was adding `Appbrain` Sdk for Ads to my app `gradle`

```
compile 'com.appbrain:appbrain-sdk:14.30'
```

Now I'm getting this error:

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.

I followed the instruction by adding `multiDexEnabled true` to my code and I get `OutOfMemoryException`

Here is my code

my `app build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.webstore.footballscores"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.7"
        multiDexEnabled true


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    }

      dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])



    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.9.3'
    compile 'com.appbrain:appbrain-sdk:14.30'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     }
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' 
       com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck=true
```

Comment: Please add your stacktrace or gradle output. the sdk you tested on would also be interesting

Comment: use `compile 'com.appbrain:appbrain-sdk:14.20'` and set `dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "Xg"

    }`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya should I add `multiDexEnabled true` or delete it ?

Comment: @Tito's Don't delete. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I followed this link and it gives me `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: `OutOfMemoryException` check your image sizes.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I followed the link again and it works , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this code block to your build.gradle in android block.

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

instead of

```
dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
```

This should solve your problem. Good luck.