# Error: Program type already present: com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.BuildConfig

Tags: android

**I am getting the following error whenever trying to generate apk**

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program
>   type already present:
>   com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.BuildConfig
>
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException:
>   Compilation failed to complete

**build.gradle(app)**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.schoolerp.kampuskonnekt'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'io.apptik.widget:multiselectspinner:1.0.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    implementation 'im.dacer:AndroidCharts:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    implementation 'com.roger.catloadinglibrary:catloadinglibrary:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.valdesekamdem.library:md-toast:0.9.0'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.jaychang:simplerecyclerview:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.+'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:smsverifycatcher:0.3.1'
    implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.github.pedromassango:doubleClick:v1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.5l@aar'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'
    implementation 'org.quanqi:android-holo-graph:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.4.7'
    implementation 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.1.7'
    implementation 'im.dacer:AndroidCharts:1.0.4'
    implementation project(':librarysticky')
    implementation project(':libraryexpandlist')
    implementation project(':filepicker')
    implementation project(':expandablerecyclerview')
    implementation project(':drawroutemap')
}
```

**build.gradle(Module.expandablerecyclerview)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

//ext {
//  bintrayRepo = 'maven'
//  bintrayName = 'expandablerecyclerview'
//
//  publishedGroupId = 'com.thoughtbot'
//  libraryName = 'expandablerecyclerview'
//  artifact = 'expandablerecyclerview'
//
//  libraryDescription = 'Custom Android RecyclerViewAdapters that collapse and expand'
//
//  siteUrl = 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view'
//  gitUrl = 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view.git'
//
//  libraryVersion = '1.4'
//
//  developerId = 'mandybess'
//  developerName = 'Amanda Hill'
//  developerEmail = 'amandabesshill@gmail.com'
//
//  licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
//  licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
//  allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
//}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.4"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  //android
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

  //unit tests
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.2.1'
  testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.5'
}
//apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
//apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Remove `implementation project(':expandablerecyclerview')`

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Error: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list.
# methods: 66104 > 65536 @NileshRathod

Comment: @SayanRay Solved this yet?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya solved

Comment: @SayanRay where was problem ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya the problem is that,implementation of  Module it automatically add same dependency twice

Comment: @SayanRay I already told you. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Error: Program type already present:

At first, remove **`DUPLICATE`** entry from your **`dependencies`** .

**FYI**

> Couldn't Solve Error: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex
>   file. Try supplying a main-dex list. # methods: 66104 > 65536

Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 (API level 21) use the Dalvik runtime for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this limitation, you can add the multidex support library to your project:

You should add **`multiDexEnabled`**

```
defaultConfig {
        ....
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
```

And

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

For more information, visit [**`DexIndexOverflowException`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests).